# iTunes sync error -50

Tags: macos, itunes, ios, data-synchronization, error

I recently tried to sync my iOS device, but I got a message similar to this one:

[image: unknown error -50 itunes]

I tried googling around, and people generally recommended to disable syncing photos to fix this, but in my case syncing photos was already off.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed this by deleting a large video from my iPhone.

Even though I still had about 3 GB left, it seems that iTunes wants there to remain some free space on the iPhone before syncing.

Once I had about 4 GB left, it started syncing again normally.

I hope this helps someone, and for god's sake Apple you could've included a less cryptic error message for such a simple issue.